# PhpStorm: Is there a way to show project name or path in the editor

Tags: phpstorm

When PhpStorm goes to full screen or switch between multi projects, it's hard to recongnize which project you're editing...

[image: editor window]

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question but why the [project name] in Project Tool window does not fit your needs?

Comment: Do you actually need a project name or perhaps Content Root path? Project name is shown in main window app bar. Full file name is shown in a tool tip when you hover over the editor tab. If you have more than one project or module opened in the same window, consider using **Custom Scope and File Coloring** -- it will draw that colors as editor tab background. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-file-colors.html. There is also a **"File Path" popup** that shows a popup menu with file path split into individual menu entries so you can navigate there in your OS file manager.

Comment: There are also a **Path Title** and **Custom Title** plugins (not sure if they still work now as they are from mid 2017)

Comment: @user10550971 I prefer hide projects tool window.